# Why threading is not performing correctly in c#?

Tags: c#

Hi I have a method like below:

```
void Foo
{
MethodInvoker method=delegate{
frm2 frm=new frm2();
frm.show();
}
```

and I have a datagridview control inside this form which does a heavy loading from DB and loads data inside this datagridview in frm2.

the problem is that the main thread(form1 thread) is freezed at time when the data is attached to datagridview in frm2.Why is this happening.

I created two different projects and separate frm2 and form1 in these 2 projects and the results are ok and no freeze is happening to none of them.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I think there is one single thread for any UI manipulation in WinForms.
If you are doing DB retrieval within Form constructor, then this is performed in the UI thread, and all forms freeze.

You should create a new thread to fetch your data from DB and set it later in the UI in the UI thread.